# NoClassDefFoundError when deploying WebLogic application from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic, classpath

I'm working with Maven and WebLogic. When building my application with Maven, I can successfully install it manually on my local Weblogic, using the Admin Console.

When trying to deploy this same application on the server using Eclipse IDE, I get a **NoClassDefFoundError**. (I tried both with *"Publish as virtual application"* and *"Publish as an exploded archive"* in the Oracle Weblogic Server tools in Eclipse).

The structure of my application is the following:

```
MyApp.ear contains:
- MyWar1.war
- MyWar2.war
- MyEjb.jar (ejb module, using maven-ejb-plugin)
  - MyJar.jar (another project, as dependency)
```

And it's this `MyJar.jar` that seems to be not found in the classpath. I've checked that in the Eclipse settings, this project is include in the **Java Build Path\Project**, **Java Build Path/Order and Export** and in the **Deployment Assembly** for the `MyEjb` project.

I've also checked the folder build by Eclipse, `eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\MyApp`, where I can see the folder `APP-INF\lib\MyJar.jar` with the corresponding `.class` files. And when I try to manually manually install this folder, I got the same error (NoClassDefFoundError).

I'm using Weblogic 10.3.3, Maven 3.2.1, Eclipse 4.4.0 (20140612-0600) and Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 7.2.1.201407111426.

Any ideas how I can investigate this problem ?

Comment: Have your compared your exploded ear that works manually (just a simple `jar xvf MyApp.ear`) to your exploded ear from eclipse to see what's different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the dependencies from `APP-INF/lib/` to `lib/` folder seems to fix the problem, but I have no idea why.